# New line inside itemize causes excessive spacing

Tags: spacing, itemize

I'm trying to do this:

```
text
\begin{itemize}
\item title
\\
text
\item title
\\
text
\end{itemize}
text
```

Unfortunately, when I add a double \ after the first bullet point title, lots of blank lines get created before and after the itemize. And if I don't, the text just appears right after the bullet point title; I wanted a new line.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Edit: Tried creating a document with just this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}
text
\begin{itemize}
\item title
\\
text
\item title
\\
text.
\end{itemize}
text
\end{document}
```

Problem didn't appear. But it does in my real document. Not much different there except there's far more actual text. Weird..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please paste your exact code, preferably in form of a small, compilable document, and use the `{}` button (or Ctrl+K, or indent each line by 4 spaces) to display your code verbatim? It's difficult to help if only a modified version of your code is available.

Comment: Distance between `itemize` and text above and below list are not changed. However, space between items, which are terminated by `\\ ` is increased for blank line which is inserted by `\\ `, Why you like to terminated items on such (very wrong) way?

Comment: Try replacing the double-backslash cases with all-blank lines.

Comment: Mico's solution creates a new line and indents further. Didn't intend the further indents, but... Good enough, thanks.

Comment: Your claims doesn't holds. Please show us result which you obtain with your MWE when you use as it is and when you remove all `\\ ` from list!

Comment: You need to add more information about your “real document”. Are you using `setspace` or similar?

Answer (score 7):

- it is not clear, what is your problem.
- terminating items with `\\` is bad idea. It causes your problems, so * newer ever* use it in list!
- if you use standard `article` document class, like

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{itemize}
\item title of bullet point
some text, but keep the indent
\item title of bullet point
some text, but keep the indent
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

then you obtain the following result:

[image]

- however, `amsart` document class suppress default vertical spaces in lists:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{itemize}
\item title of bullet point
some text, but keep the indent
\item title of bullet point
some text, but keep the indent
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

so you obtain tight list format:

[image]

- if you like to increase vertical spaces between list and text above/below it and between list items, then you can help yourself with use of `enumitem` package. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=6pt, itemsep=6pt} % adjust those spaces according to your wishes
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{itemize}
\item title of bullet point
some text, but keep the indent
\item title of bullet point
some text, but keep the indent
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

- more about `enumitem` package you can find in the package documentation. It is part of your LaTeX installation or you can find on CTAN (just google for `enumitem.sty`)

Comment: Nice explanation, really helpful definitions...